# Connect from Linux laptop to a Windows PC desktop

Tags: networking

I have a laptop running Linux Ubuntu and a desktop, without monitor, running Windows 10. Both in the same room. I wrongly thought that I would be able to connect the desktop to the laptop using a HDMI cable, but now I realize that the HDMI port in the laptop is only for output.

How could I use the laptop as if it were the monitor of the desktop? Could I just connect remotely to the desktop and view what would be its video output? What would produce less sluggish interaction? I'd have in mind that I could get the Windows desktop as a window in a Linux workspace.

Computers have RJ-45 (I have LAN cable), Bluetooth, WiFi (both connected to router), USB.

Changing the OS on any computer is not an option, but I could install programs on both.

Comment: Sharing a monitor between two computers is not simply straightforward.  There are good ideas in this article here: 
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-connect-two-or-more-computers-to-one-monitor/   .  Truly (very truly) better to get an inexpensive monitor (used) for the desktop computer

Comment: @John: that's not exactly running two PCs with one monitor. It's a laptop + desktop, and I wonder how to "view" the graphic output of the desktop.

Comment: There is not much other way to do this. I think what you are trying to do is very difficult.  That is why I suggest another monitor.

Comment: This can be done via a [KVM switch](https://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/), which is also mentioned in the link provided by @John, or via configuring RDP on the desktop PC.  RDP would be the easiest solution, as you can place the RDP client session on its own Ubuntu Workspace, which can be resized as required or maximized to full screen.

Comment: I would either use a KVM or Teamviewer or similar solution.